# Swift POST request don't work

Tags: swift, swift2, httprequest

I'm trying to make a post request with Swift. my goal is to post the accesstoken facebook to a server but does not work. here's the code:

```
let myUrlfb = NSURL(string: "MyApiServer");

let requestfb = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrlfb!);

requestfb.HTTPMethod = "POST";// Compose a query string


//We make the post string
let postStringfb = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

requestfb.HTTPBody = postStringfb.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(requestfb) {
                    data, response, error in

    if error != nil
    {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return

    }
```

the answer is as follows:

```
{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"child \"access_token\" fails because [access_token is required]","validation":{"source":"payload","keys":["access_token"]}})
```

Comment: I've already checked that the token is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this way you can consume POST web services:

```
func webApi() {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "your url")!)
                    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            var string = "access_token="
            var postString =       string.stringByAppendingString(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
                request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                        print("response = \(response)")
                    }

                    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
                }
                task.resume()
            }

    }//End of webapi function
```

Comment: actually I wrote it as well . but the code that should not work is what I posted

Comment: i updated code add access_token=fbtoken may solve ur issue

Answer (score 1):

From Api request you can see that access token is missing and is required. Your http body should be in specific format like "keys":["access_token"]. Try reading api docs for more information. Once you meet specifications it should work. Currently you are just posting access token as string

Comment: reading the documentation known that accepts the token field in string format