# Facebook login with Swift and Node JS - Access Token

Tags: node.js, swift, facebook

I am building an app in Swift and would like to integrate login with facebook. I managed to add a login button and login in Swift.
I'm stuck on sending the access token to the Node JS server and using the graph api to access user data.
The access token is a struct.
How do I send the access token to the server with Swift?
This is the struct from facebook-swift-sdk for the access token.

```
public struct AccessToken {
/// The application id for this token.
public let appId: String
/// An opaque authentication token.
public let authenticationToken: String
/// The logged in user identifier.
public let userId: String?
/// The date the token was last refreshed.
public let refreshDate: NSDate
/// The expirate date for the token.
public let expirationDate: NSDate
/// Known granted permissions.
public let grantedPermissions: Set<FacebookCore.Permission>?
/// Known declined permissions.
public let declinedPermissions: Set<FacebookCore.Permission>?
/**
   Creates a new access token instance.

   - parameter appId:               Optional application id for this token. Default: `SDKSettings.appId`.
   - parameter authenticationToken: An opaque authentication token.
   - parameter userId:              Optional logged in user identifier.
   - parameter refreshDate:         Optional date the token was last refreshed (defaults to current date).
   - parameter expirationDate:      Optional expiration date (defaults to `NSDate.distantFuture()`).
   - parameter grantedPermissions:  Set of known granted permissions.
   - parameter declinedPermissions: Set of known declined permissions.
   */
public init(appId: String = default, authenticationToken: String, userId: String? = default, refreshDate: NSDate = default, expirationDate: NSDate = default, grantedPermissions: Set<FacebookCore.Permission>? = default, declinedPermissions: Set<FacebookCore.Permission>? = default)
}

extension AccessToken {

public static var current: FacebookCore.AccessToken?

public static func refreshCurrentToken(completion: ((FacebookCore.AccessToken?, ErrorType?) -> Void)? = default)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: this link may help check once http://stackoverflow.com/a/39203067/3400991

Comment: Thanks, the link looks good, but I am using the new Swift facebook SDK library and there is no tokenString in the access token.

Comment: update code along with structure format , it may help to resolve issue